# Icon for election is different on community bulletin for main and meta sites

Tags: bug, design, per-site-meta, election, community-bulletin

Physics SE has an ongoing election.

Here is a screenshot of the community bulletin visible on the [main site](https://physics.stackexchange.com):

> [image: main green icon]

This is what I see when I'm on the [physics meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com):

> [image: meta grey icon]

I believe that the meta version should have a greenish icon instead: the election page which that link leads to is on the main site (the URL does not mention meta), and it has the standard greenish physics color.

Presumably, this bug shows up for all elections, so I'm putting it here on the main meta site.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to be a bug at all.

The colour schemes match the sites - meta is more muted. If you have a look at any notifications on meta sites - they use that muted palette.

The election is for the site as a whole, it's not a separate election for main and meta - so the notifications point to the same link, no matter whether you see the notification on main or meta.

Comment: I thought the icon color reflected the site the post is on. I know the sidebar on SO shows meta posts in gray and normal posts in color.

Comment: The election is one of those weird things that is across both. You don't have separate elections for main and meta.

Comment: Right, but if the election post is hosted on the main site, wouldn't it then be a main-site post?